# Non-linear model like GMM for panel data with an interaction term

Tags: applied-econometrics, capital-mobility

For my dissertation I am looking at regressing net capital outflows against financial openness and GDP per capita like in Reinhardt, Ricci and Tressel (2013). To deal with potential endogeneity in this paper, I was hoping to use something like a system-GMM model, but it seems that this is unsuitable as the baseline regression includes an interaction term between financial openness and GDP per capita (as theory suggests that greater financial openness would mean more inflows in a poor country but outflows in a rich country). Could anyone recommend an econometric model that is suitable for this situation?